# Posting XML to web service using SOAP Savon gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, xml, web-services, soap, savon

I'm working with ruby and Savon 2. I have been given the following SOAP example:

```
POST /WebApi/Services/b2bapi.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.nationsphotolab.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://api.nationsphotolab.com/AddNewOrder"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AddNewOrder xmlns="http://api.nationsphotolab.com/">
      <orderXml>string</orderXml>
      <passport>
        <Source>string</Source>
        <Hash>string</Hash>
      </passport>
    </AddNewOrder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried a bunch of different methods of creating the XML, first using XmlMarkup builder, and then just building a hash and passing it into the savon client call.

The error I've been getting: 
`Savon::SOAPFault ((soap:Server) Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.):`

Here's the request:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://api.nationsphotolab.com/WebApi/Services/b2bapi.asmx?wsdl")
response = client.call(:add_new_order, message: data)
```

With data being an XML created using XmlMarkup builder. 
Attached is a screenshot of data.

Please let me know if I can provide anymore information

Example data:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like the API is expecting the `orderXML` element to be a string. I think the problem is that you put XML into the `orderXML` element, when the API is expecting it to contain a string.

Escaping the contents of the `orderXML` element and sending it as a string should solve the problem.

The code below shows one way of escaping XML strings:

`order_xml_string.encode(xml: :text)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to alleviate the problem. I tried wrapping in cdata tags but I think the main problem is that the whole payload is being passed as a string. How can I pass it as an object with only the orderXML string and passport as params?

Comment: @BradleyT. can you try to execute the request with `log_level: :debug` (option for the `Savon.client` initialization) ? That will print the request/response and make it easy for you to verify if your code is escaping the whole payload or only the orderXML element as intended.

Comment: also. naturally you'd only need to add: `.encode(xml: :text)` to the variable that contains the `orderXML` data

Comment: I think that the problem is that the entire payload is currently one big string, when only the order, source, and hash should be strings. When I put a pry in and look at the xml payload that is being passed in, it's one big string including the version, encoding, envelope, body, etc.